# Equally distribute array of numbers into x subsets of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a large array of numbers that I need to distribute into x ranges of numbers, such that each range contains an equal number of elements from the original array.

For example, when `x = 4` , the following array

```
[1, 1, 2.5, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11.2, 14, 25, 35, 50, 75, 85.5, 100, 120, 128.9, 150, 200, 260]
```

would produce an array of length `x + 1` with the following

```
[1, 6.5, 30, 110, 260]
```

- 1 is the lowest value in the array
- 6.5 is the midpoint of 6 and 7
- 30 is the midpoint of 25 and 35
- 110 is the midpoint of 100 and 120
- 260 is the highest value

Essentially, this will give me 4 ranges of numbers 1-6.5, 6.5-30, 30-110, and 110-260.  Each range would contain 5 numbers of the original array.

**Needs to be able to handle a dynamic number of elements that will not necessarily be divided evenly by x.**

I asked [this question on Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662235/equally-distribute-range-of-numbers-into-x-subsets-of-numbers) but was told it was more of a programming question.

Comment: This is indeed something you could solve with a program, but it's a bit too simplistic for this site.  The only way to answer it is to do the work for you, which no one here is going to do.  If you're interested in understanding how to go about creating a basic  javascript function for this use case, look into how a For Loop works, and the very basic Math.floor, and Array.push methods.

Comment: @Ryan : What code have you tried so far using javascript ?

Comment: What if `x` does not divide the length of the array?

Comment: I need the remainder to be equally distributed over the ranges.  Therefore if the input array has 18 elements and x=4, the output array should have ranges which contain [5, 5, 4, 4].  Does that make sense?

Comment: @RyanDantzler - durnig the loop to create the subsets, if remainder is not equal to 0, add 1 to subset size and subtract 1 from remainder. Eventually remainder goes to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question , the following javascript code should satisfy your requirements, I've tested its correctness with a few values of x, but you might want to check if this code applies to all possible test cases for your problem.

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 2.5, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11.2, 14, 25, 35, 50, 75, 85.5, 100, 120, 128.9, 150, 200, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265];
total_elem = arr.length;
var x = 5;
var each_set_elem = total_elem / x;
var i = 1;
var temp = [];
temp.push(arr[0]);
for (i = each_set_elem; i < total_elem; i += each_set_elem) {
  this_elem = (arr[i] + arr[i - 1]) / 2;
  temp.push(this_elem);
}
temp.push(arr[total_elem - 1]);
console.log(temp);
```

This code satisfies the test case in the question as well as for x=5 it spits out the correct 6 points so that the 5 ranges each have 4 elements from the given array set.

Comment: Will this handle an odd number of elements in the input array? Because I need it to be dynamic.

Comment: @RyanDantzler : yes, this will work for arrays with odd number of elements as well , as long as you can divide the total number of elements into the respective sets of elements over the range you want , for eg. 25 elements into 5 sets of 5 elements each, check my updated snippet, I've shown the odd numbered case here with 25 elements and x=5.

Comment: What I mean is, it needs to be able to handle a number of elements that will not be exactly divided by x.

Comment: @RyanDantzler : You'll have to make some edits to my code though to make it run when x does not divide the length of the array, in any case, this should be a good starting point for you.